# I accidentally hit Ctl Alt F<num>. How do I return to the GUI?

Tags: xorg, shortcut-keys, tty

I'm using 12.04, I accidentally used <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> and got a black full screen with command line cursor (Terminal).  How can I go back to the normal Unity screen?

Comment: Another way, just press Alt + right or left arrow couple times, until you get out of gui. Ubuntu by default has like 6 black screens (ttys), and 7th is the gui

Answer (score 71):

Press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, that is the default graphical tty.

Linux systems use to have 12 [terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal): 6 for text (<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>) and 6 for graphical (<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>)

Comment: To provide a little more information, Ctl+Alt+F1-F6 are your tty terminals. I'm not sure the purpose of F9. desgua has the right answer, though. +1

Comment: F9 is for graphical.

Comment: Note that Ctrl is only needed if you're in the GUI; once you hit a text console, you can switch between them with just Alt+F1-F7.

Comment: On LinuxMint it is CTRL+ALT+F8

Answer (score 7):

`Ctrl+Alt+F7` did not work for me, here are the alternatives:

1. For those who have a `Fn` button, try `Ctrl+Alt+Fn+F7`
2. if all fails, try the command: `chvt 7`

Comment: doesn;t work in my case! please check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186897/ubuntu-guest-os-in-vmware-shows-a-blank-screen-if-ctrlaltdel-key-is-pressed

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+F1` helped me to return GUI back on Ubuntu 18.04 when I accidentally pressed `Ctrl+Alt+F9`.

Comment: You need press additional because your keyboard has other Function given to the Fn's keys like volume, screen refreshing and brightness settings I do guess.