# Ubuntu (guest OS in Vmware) shows a blank screen if CTRL+ALT+DEL key is pressed

Tags: 19.04, vmware, wayland, guest-os

I'm not an expert of Ubuntu but I'm learning it while using it for everyday tasks. my experience has been good so far. just that I face a few glitches sometimes.

I have this weird problem from the very beginning, usually I restart but that's not the solution because often the processes are running and I just simply can't kill them like that.

I use VMware to run Ubuntu 19.04. on Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key combination is very common to Lock and Unlock the screen and system level options. Sometimes accidentally I press them and I get this

[image: Ubuntu in VMware after press Ctrl+Alt+Del]

I don't know if that's VMWare or LINUX itself but then nothing works and I have to shutdown the guest and restart it.

My questions are:

1. What exactly is this blank screen with cursor blinking? Is it that OS has crashed or the GUI Wayland has shut down? Or is it some pause state?
2. What should I do in this case that I can preserve my work or better yet resume it?

P.S: Just found out that it's not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>. The way my laptop keyboard is, I confirmed I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>. I found [What does "Ctrl + Alt + F12" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277517/what-does-ctrl-alt-f12-do/277539) but nothing works, and after like few minutes (5+ or more) the virtual machine restarts.

Comment: I'm sure you've found a solution by now but for other people experiencing this issue, here's what fixed this and worked for me (The issue turned out to be my drive being 100% full!) Full steps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1240673/1082582

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the login console that you bring up with ctrl alt F1/F3 to me, but something should appear after a few seconds. Also normally ctrl alt del bring up the logout page, maybe it's the vm doing its thing? Try ctrl alt F1 to close it again.

hope it helps :)

Comment: Nope, nothing happens. the cursor keeps blinking! I added more detail. Please check